# api call from angular app from browser to an ssl spring or flask service , api calls fails with ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT during preflight?

Tags: flask, nginx, ssl, tomcat

The api calls fails only from browser. When making the api calls from service to service using .crt and .key file the services responds with the content for the calls (flask to spring and vice versa)

my understanding of this issue from all the things that i have read is that the preflight doesnt contain ssl certs in them , when the preflight fails api call fails too due to CORS policy.
Any idea on solving this issue or different approach to enable a ssl verified api calls from browser to services would be helpful - thanks

Tried nginx proxy pass to flask services and return 200 to OPTIONS method alone ,
but since the server block is configured with ssl_client_verfiy on ;
not working any different approach on this proxy pass that verifies client cert for all except OPTIONS method would be helpful.

nginx angular web app :

```
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80;
         server_name ex.example.in;
         return 301 https://ex.example.in/$request_uri;
    }
    server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         listen [::]:443 ssl;
         server_name ex.example.in;
         root /root/live/Dist;
         server_tokens off;
         index index.html index.htm;
    
         ssl_certificate /example.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /example.key;
         access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
    
         location ~ \.(html)$ {
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31536000";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    
        location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    
         location / {
             # First attempt to server request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
        }
    }
```

nginx for flask app:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name demo.example.in;    

    ssl_certificate /example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /example.key;
    #ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ##ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  
    # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # modern configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
    ssl_client_certificate /example.ca-bundle;
    ssl_verify_depth 3;
    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    
    location / {
       if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                  add_header Content-Length 0;
                  add_header Content-Type "application/json";
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        return 200;
       }
       proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ; 
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ; 
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9098/;
       proxy_set_header Host      $http_host;
       proxy_set_header SSL_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
       proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
       proxy_ssl_name $host;
       proxy_set_header X-cert $ssl_client_raw_cert; 
     }

}
```

required flow for ssl verification:
webapp browser -> nginx(verify client ssl and proxy to flask) -> flask app.

Screenshot of nginx logs:

[api call from flask :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqrqp.png)
[api call from browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLYp.png)
both images show a headers for the proxied request to flask service

X-Client-Authentication: NONE for browser calls and
X-Client-Authentication: SUCCESS for api call from flask requests with certs .

Seems that the browser is not sending certificate for the api calls .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.